# How can I switch between gnome-shell and unity without logging off?

Tags: unity, gnome

How can I switch between unity and gnome-shell without logging of my account. This will help me to switch between both anytime.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, and

- to run unity, execute `unity --replace`
- to run gnome-shell, execute `gnome-shell --replace`

Comment: how to do this without terminal

Comment: Press Alt+F2 and type those commands in. I put it in my answer, but will edit it to make it a little more prominent. Glad to help!